# Multipart config location, getter

Tags: java, servlets

```
   <multipart-config>
        <location>C://pathToFile </location>
        <max-file-size>2097152</max-file-size>
        <max-request-size>20971520</max-request-size>
        <file-size-threshold>5242880</file-size-threshold>
    </multipart-config>
```

How can I get the path from location inside my servlet? I tried getRealPath but that's not it.

Answer (score 0):

If you are trying to use this location as a static variable for uploading your files it is not the right thing.

The location element is used for storing files temporarily look [here](https://docs.oracle.com/javaee/6/tutorial/doc/gmhal.html):

Comment: Hi, let us say I want to a reference to this location while fully aware that the files stored there are temp files how do I get it. Sometimes we have to break the rules.